# Mysql query relating to count and date time

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'transaction' which contains columns transaction_id, sender_id,amount, date_time,payee_id .
I want to find transactions which are more than five made by sender_id in one day by single sender. 
i tried
mysql> select * from transaction where sender_id count() =5 and datedif() =1;

Comment: Give here the sample data for the tables

Comment: Start with basic mysql tutorials online as this is clearly your first encounter with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will be helpful for you.

```
select sender_id, count(sender_id) as count  
from `transaction`
group by sender_id, date(date_time)
having count>5
```

this will return the list of sender_ids who have more than 5 transactions
if you also need the list of that transactions than you need this

```
select t.*
from (
select sender_id, count(sender_id) as count  
from `transaction`
group by sender_id, date(date_time)
having count>5
) as senders
inner join `transaction` as t on t.sender_id=senders.sender_id
```

PS. for good performance I recommend run second query on MySQL server with version 5.6.10 or higher